# Which space is $L^1(\partial\Omega)$?

Tags: lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, manifolds-with-boundary, submanifold, trace-map

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $M$ be a $d$-dimensional properly embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary.

In the context of the [trace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator), I've seen the usage of the $L^p$-space $L^1(\partial M)$. What is this space?

Usually, if $\Omega\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$, $L^1(\Omega)$ is a shorthand notation for the space $L^1\left(\left.\lambda^{\otimes d}\right|_\Omega\right)$, where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

But I doubt that $L^1(\partial M)$ is really denoting $L^1\left(\left.\lambda^{\otimes d}\right|_{\partial M}\right)$ here, since $\lambda^{\otimes d}(\partial M)=0$ and hence this space is rather boring.

My most probable guess is that $L^1(\partial M)$ has to be understood as a shorthand notation for $L^1(\sigma_{\partial M})$, where $\sigma_{\partial M}$ denotes the surface measure on $\mathcal B(\partial M)$.

> Am I right? If not, what's denoted by $L^1(\partial M)$?

Comment: You're exactly right that it refers to $L^1$ of the Riemannian surface measure. Note that this is consistent with the notation $L^1(\Omega)$, since the Lesbegue measure is also (up to some constant) given by the Riemannian surface measure on $\Omega$. This is a point where the geometry of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is really important: Measures do not "see" sub-manifolds with positive co-dimension, but the Riemannian structure clearly does.

Comment: When you say that it's consistent  with the notaton $L^1(\Omega)$, you mean that, **if $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$**, then $\sigma_\Omega=\left.\lambda^{\otimes d}\right|_\Omega$, right?

Comment: Right. You seemed to be using $\Omega$ to denote an open domain in your question text, so I just repeated your notation.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou In the question $\Omega$ is any Borel subset, but that doesn't matter. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I've encountered a highly related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4123318/47771. Could you please take a look?